# Error group by character column in dataframe - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using dplyr package and want to group datafarame by column in class character. This give me "Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "character"".

```
abc1<- group_by(frazy_i_lp_new_Full$lp)%>%summarise(wysz = sum(`ilośc wyszukań`))
```

How can I group columns in dataframe grouped by column containing characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify your dataframe first, not by $

```
abc1<- frazy_i_lp_new_Full %>% group_by(lp) %>% summarise(wysz = sum(`ilośc wyszukań`))
```